# Ideal mysqldump options for backups

Tags: database, backup, mysql, database-backups

I'm creating a backup script for our database servers, and thought I'd ask if there are any preferred options to include with `mysqldump`. The script will be called from cron every 6-24 hours.

We use InnoDB exclusively.

Our databases are rather large, and I'll most likely dump clusters of tables individually, as opposed to the entire database in one go.

For now, I'm thinking of including:

```
--opt # enabled by default
--quote-names # enabled by default
--single-transaction
--skip-comments
```

Any other suggestions or pointers for creating good, reliable dump files?

Comment: How long does the dump take? do you need a reliable or a quicker backup? is your backup stopping other database changes? are you OK with that?

Comment: Speed is potentially an issue, yes, but more than anything I don't want any disruptions to applications accessing the database.

Comment: since you are using the `--single-transaction` option show that you need a dump of the database in a consistent state. look into @zerkms proposition

Comment: be aware that --opt will lock all your tables . . .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose you to just set up one more server (slave) with mysql and replicate data there (from the main, master one).

If you'll need a plain text dump - you can always do it from the slave without hurting master.